# Bevel Weight on edges

Tags: edges, bevel

What is significance of Bevel Weight? In what circumstances it should be used and how it changes model geometry?

Answer (score 3):

Just to illustrate *Bevel Weight* with some quick gifs:

*Bevel weight on edges*

[image]

*Bevel weight on vertices*

[image]

Comment: Very easy explaination. I love it.

Answer (score 2):

In the documentation we read:

> This edge property, a value between $0.0$ to $1.0$, is used by the *Bevel Modifier* to control the bevel intensity of the edges. This operator enters an interactive mode (a bit like transform tools), where by moving the mouse (or typing a value with the keyboard) you can set the bevel weight of selected edges. If two or more edges are selected, this operator alters the average weight of the edges.

See also [bevel tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VqmcBgJxkJg).

Comment: Is it like if Bevel weight is applied then future bevel operations will be affacted by oast bevel operations will have no effect on it?

Comment: @MathRunner7 I added a tutorial link to my answer.

Comment: It was really helpful to understand Bevel Weight operation. Thank You.